# Resetting dropdowns(especially menus) when a link is clicked in a Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

On a normal website you can open all the submenus/dropdowns you want and when you go to a new page it loads and everything is nicely reset but in a single page application since only a sub section of the page changes a method for resetting the page needs to be used.

This is the basic HTML structure of my menu. It is pretty common except for maybe the `dropdown-toggle` **directive** and the `data-group` **attribute**.

`dropdown-toggle` value is the ID of the element who's visibility is to be toggled.

`data-group` value is just to group dropdowns together. This is used to prevent two dropdowns from the same group being visible at the same time. If a dropdown from group "navigation" is visible and you try to open another from the same group, the currently visible dropdown will first be closed.

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#/">Dashboard</a>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a dropdown-toggle="submenu-repairs">Repairs</a>
        <ul id="submenu-repairs" data-group="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#/repairs/take-in">Take In</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/repairs/search">Search</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a dropdown-toggle="submenu-customers">Repairs</a>
        <ul id="submenu-customers" data-group="navigation">
            <li>
                <a href="#/customers/register">Register</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <a href="#/customers/search">Search</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**Problem**

In a Single Page Application(especially on a mobile device) you may have submenus inside submenus which take up a lot of screen and when a user clicks one of the links the browser does not reload a whole new page so therefore by default the menus are still open.

On a small device with little screen space it may appear like nothing happened when the link was clicked.

The goal is to close the submenus once a link is clicked and here are some ways I have been thinking of doing it:

1. Attach an event listener to every `<a>` element in the DOM which has a `href` attribute that is not equal to an empty string. That event listener would somehow check if any submenus are open and close them.
2. If **Angular** dispatches an event whenever the route/url changes then I could create a listener for that event which could somehow check for any open submenus and close them.

If number 1 is the best way then what do you do when a new view loads, do I have to attach event listeners to all the `<a>` elements in it?

Is number 2 even possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could listen to the `<ul />` which contains the `<a />` elements, as the clicks on the latter will propagate all the way up the DOM.

Once the `click` event reaches the `<ul />` element, you can toggle an `active` class which would hide/show the submenu.

[Here's an example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/x3nRQdS7M1F6MjnHbSgR?p=preview)

**Edit: Code examples:**

Toggle the `$scope.active_submenus` boolean within the controller

```
      $scope.active_submenus = false;

      $scope.toggle_nav = function()
      {
        console.log( 'toggling', $scope.active_submenus );
        $scope.active_submenus = !$scope.active_submenus;
      }
```

Update `active` class based on `ng-class`

```
<ul ng-click="toggle_nav()" ng-class="{ active: active_submenus }">
```

Comment: It's not getting the dropdowns to work that's the problem. The problem is how to close all open dropdowns on the page after the user clicks a link in a single page application. Since the whole page does not reload in a SPA the dropdowns are still open and taking up space in the viewport.